# Is it safe to write to file's extents directly while the FS is r/w?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, swap, block-device, loop-device

Given any file on an ext4 filesystem, it is possible (using `filefrag -v`) to get the list of real offsets+lengths where that file is located on the underlying block device.

**Is it safe to open the device and write to them, all that while the filesystem is mounted read-write? Can it cause fs corruption?**
I'm asking because I'm going to implement an alternative `loop` driver, which will bypass the filesystem layer completely, therefore having much better performance.

If I remember correctly, swapfile is implemented exactly that way. Please correct me if told something wrong.

Is the answer filesystem-dependent? What can happen if the file is suddenly deleted, and these offsets become reused for some **metadata**?

Finally, is there a way to lock a file from being relocated by `e4defrag` or similar things? What is the best way to prevent a file from being deleted (being in kernel space)? Is there some kernel internals I can use to get the list of file's extents?

Comment: If it is safe, there is even no need to implement a driver. We can just setup device mappings using dm-linear. But how to protect the file from being deleted or relocated by the FS layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the writes are *only* to the blocks of the file, then it wouldn't corrupt the ext4 filesystem.  However, there is a definitely a bigger risk that some error in the code *could* corrupt the filesystem, which wouldn't happen with a regular loop device that is only using the file mapping.

The question is whether writing directly to the block device will actually make a difference in performance?

You can prevent the file from being deleted by marking it immutable with `chattr +i FILENAME`.